# Will Symlink do as im hoping - treat one folder same as another

Tags: directory, symlink

I want to symlink:

```
/var/www/ThisFolder
```

to this folder

```
/var/www/htdocs/Thisfolder
```

I.e Symlink the folder that is in a non web accessible directory to link to one that is.

I plan to do this via:

```
ln -s /var/www/ThisFolder /var/www/htdocs/Thisfolder
```

**Will my server then treat the folder outside the root as if it were inside the root?**

Answer (score 0):

Permissions on symbolic links are kind of funny. If you don't have permissions to view your target folder (/var/www/htdocs/Thisfolder) you wont be able to access it through the symlink. The permissions you will see by doing an ls -l on your symlink will show its permissions for renaming/unlinking the symlink, not for the target.